# how to save generated pdf file using wkhtmltopdf through system command

Tags: email, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Hi I am able to generate pdf file from html page using wkhtmltopdf library. I am generating pdf file through system commands not using php and methods.

```
$command = "wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter ".$myFile." ".$outfile;
system($command);
```

Now i want to sed this generated pdf file as an attachment to the email.For that i have to save the pdf report to my local directory using system commands. `How can i do that?`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661

A better and easier way to do it is to use a framework like Zend framework (Zend_mail):
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Answer (score 0):

**Mention output file path as a last parameter**

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf  --page-size 'A4' --viewport-size 2480x3508  --margin-top '10' --margin-bottom '10' --margin-right '0' --margin-left '0' --header-spacing '1' --footer-spacing '0'  pdfoutputFile.pdf`